# Block gradle release-build if git is not committed

Tags: git, android-studio, gradle

I need my gradle.build to throw a `GradleException` if I have some files which isn't commited to git, when I make a release build.

I have been trying it this way:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            preBuild.dependsOn('verifyVersionControl')
        }
    }
}

task verifyVersionControl {
    def cmd = "git diff-files"
    def proc = cmd.execute()
    ext.status = proc.text.trim()
    doLast {
        if (!(ext.status == ""))
            throw new GradleException("Git not clean, commit changes before running release build")
    }
}
```

But this code will trigger even when I just run my application through AndroidStudio.